# Code First versus Database First?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, database-first

Estou acostumado a criar projetos no asp.net-MVC com Entity Framework Database First.
A partir de uma modelagem, é criado o banco de dados e o sistema.

Porém, vejo uma grande quantidade de programadores preferir Code First, onde o banco de dados depende do sistema.

Qual as **diferenças** entre as duas?
Digo no sentido prático, qual os **prós e contras** de cada abordagem?
O que **muda** na arquitetura de um projeto e na maneira de desenvolver o sistema?

Comment: O que está faltando na resposta fornecida?

Comment: A resposta é ótima, mas ainda não ficou claro pra mim como isso afeta o desenvolvimento do sistema em um time.. Como fica a questão da aplicação da modelagem do sistema e os dbas? e pra dar manutenção depois?

Comment: No *Code First* a modelagem começa nos *Models*, o banco é gerado a partir do sistema, e o DBA só tem papel **depois** que o código do sistema já foi escrito. A ideia do *Code First* é um dia poder dispensar o papel do DBA, visto que tendo um sistema implementado usando as práticas recomendadas resulta num banco de dados já otimizado.

Comment: Entendi. Mas isso não tende a tornar o banco de dados dependente demais da aplicação? Caso surja outra aplicação que use o mesmo banco, é possível ter as duas com *Code First* sem que haja risco de uma mudança na Model de uma afetar a outra através do banco?

Comment: Não existe "duas aplicações *Code First* com o mesmo banco". Como eu te disse, se o banco já existe, a segunda aplicação é necessariamente *Database First*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Diferenças

- Code First: O código é escrito primeiro. O banco de dados é gerado a partir do código;
- Database First: O banco de dados é escrito primeiro. O código da aplicação é gerado a partir do banco de dados.

## Prós e Contras

### Code First

#### Prós

- Pode trabalhar independente da tecnologia do banco de dados;
- As validações de dados não estão estritas a uma tecnologia;
- Pode construir e destruir bancos de dados gerados em instantes, através de Migrations;
- Ideal para novas aplicações;

#### Contras

- Não se acopla bem a um banco de dados já existente;
- Depende de um bom ORM, como o Entity Framework e o NHibernate, por exemplo;
- Exige constante otimização, pois a abstração de dados para alguns bancos nem sempre tem um bom desempenho;
- Validação em banco de dados é limitada. A geração do banco de dados pela aplicação nunca é 100%;
- Fraca segurança de banco de dados.

### Database First

#### Prós

- Ideal para desempenho e esquemas já existentes;
- Aplicação pode ser feita em cima de um banco de dados que já existe;
- Segurança a nível de banco mais bem ajustada;

#### Contras

- Geração de ambientes é limitada; Complexo para determinar mudanças incrementais tanto do banco de dados quanto da aplicação;
- Totalmente dependente da tecnologia de banco;
- Limitação de providers de banco que podem gerar a aplicação (ODBC ajuda, mas não resolve completamente o problema);
- Validação de dados gerada para a aplicação limitada;

## O que muda na arquitetura de um projeto e na maneira de desenvolver o sistema?

Creio que os ítens anteriores respondam bem esta pergunta. Tudo depende da realidade em que o novo sistema é construído, com mais alguns adendos.

No *Code First*, o banco de dados acompanha o crescimento do sistema. No *Database First*, todo o sistema precisa ser gerado de uma vez, e toda implementação incremental precisa ser manual.

Em contrapartida, um sistema *Code First* é verde quanto à segurança e desempenho do banco de dados. A maioria dos problemas são resolvidos por boas práticas, mas ainda assim sempre alguma coisa deixa a desejar, como uma tabela enorme ou peculiar, que exija otimização extra.

Comment: No *Database First*, onde fica a lógica de negócios? Na Controller é considerada má prática, mas se for aplicada na Model, ela não pode mais ser atualizada pelo EF...

Comment: "Na Controller é considerada má prática". Não. Depende. Quando a lógica envolve relação de dados entre *Models* não correlacionados em definição, não é má prática. No mais, as demais validações se dividem entre a) *Models*, e b) *Filters*. Isto não estava no escopo da pergunta, mas se quiser, eu posso detalhar mais.